# perl - how to find all coincidences to pattern

Tags: regex, perl

For example I have a string "babdbeb" and pattern "b.b". I want to find following substrings here:

```
bab
bdb
beb
```

What is the best way of doing this?

P.S. I'm very new to Perl programming.

Comment: This is tricky because the usual "match all" regexp operators (`/.../g`) don't return overlapping matches. I eagerly await the posting of an elegant answer. If it doesn't come then I'll post an ugly one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead pattern, see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

```
while ("babdbeb" =~ m/b(?=(.b))/g) {
        print "b$1\n";
}
```

This yields a match without the leading `b`, but allows to restart the search and find intermediate `b.b`s

Answer (score 4):

```
my $s = "babdbeb";
while ($s =~ /(b.b)/g) {
  print "$1\n";
  # decrease position where search left of by 2 (3 is length of 'b.b' -1)
  # pos() is lvalue function http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html
  pos($s) -= (length($1) -1);
}
```

output

```
bab
bdb
beb
```

Comment: @ikegami how about length()? $-[0] is perhaps more cryptic?

Comment: I suppose, though that'll require the addition of a capture in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use overlapping regex matching using positive lookahead assertion. Here is an example:

```
$\ = $/; ## adding \n after every print.

my $string = "babdbeb";
print for $string =~ /(?=(b.b))/g;
```

Output:

```
bab
bdb
beb
```